# Feature only works in Chrome, but not Firefox. How do I replace in Firefox?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, webkit, hover

I added a hoverboard on my site that flips over to reveal more text. It only works with Chrome. In Firefox, it makes the entire box turn gray on hover. How do I have it work in Chrome and do nothing in Firefox?

The place I took it from is:

http://cssdeck.com/item/122/hoverboard-3d

My site is:

(removed) - hover over "Sort Products By Availability" to see what I'm referring to.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Firefox specific prefix and overwrite the :hover classes with the regular classes. Like this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
#hover-flip:hover p  {
     background: #fff;
     color: #009EE0;
     margin: -40px 0 0 0;
     position: relative; 
}
#hover-flip:hover {
     border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
     bottom: 0;
     color: #df3e7b;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 40px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%; 
}
```

}

Remember to place this at the bottom of your css, so it overwrites the previous rules by cascading. Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Rorok_89/hV8G9/1/).

Comment: Jsfiddle is awesome. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Dipaks, nope, but I used that prefix some times and until now it always worked for me. BTW, your answer looked also good, and perhaps cleaner, so there you go a +1 from me ;)

Comment: @user1429400, better ask a new question with that issue so you can get more help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Copy and Paste all these properties starting with `-moz-`

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-transform-origin: top;
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

`-webkit-` is for chrome/safari and `-moz-` is for Firefox

Comment: Changed over everything to webkit. Doesn't look as nice in firefox as it does it chrome, but it does work!